# Pass array from my application to JS

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am developing an application in JSPs and Servlets, and I want to know if, and how it is possible to pass an array from my application in to some javascript so that i can use the Autocomplete feature from the jquery ui library.
Thanks in Advance
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's quite easy, you need to use JSON.

http://www.json.org/java/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I've downloaded the zip but im having issues unpacking it permission denied is the error im getting anywhere else i can get it from?

Comment: jquery? it's available on google CDN http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/